# Is there any way to block a URL to the crawlers if this one have an specific URL variable?

Tags: html, web, robots.txt

Im trying to block to all crawlers any URL with an specific variable beacouse Google its indexing it in duplicate.

Here are some examples:
https://www.mywebsite.com/category/product1.html?mp=1
https://www.mywebsite.com/category/product1.html

https://www.mywebsite.com/category/product2.html?mp=1
https://www.mywebsite.com/category/product2.html

Is that "mp=1" what I want to block.

Comment: You probably want to use [canonical URL](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/crawling/consolidate-duplicate-urls)

Comment: I will try it.
Thanks @HTMHell.